# How do i take a value from URL and don't display a div from template with certain value

Tags: php, html

I want to leave out a div from my `template.html` that is displayed when someone clicks on the sidebar or navigation bar. When a category is navigation_bar I want it to leave out something like a Facebook comment box. Because it is only needed on the sidebar pages.

an URL example `index.php?catagory=navigation_bar&subject=contact`

I was thinking about something like this:

```
<php?

if (isset($_GET['catagory']))
{
   $catagory = $_GET['categorie'];

    if $catagory = navigatie_bar
    {
      //here something that says: then don't display <div class="fb-comments'></div>
    }

}
?>
```

can someone help me out ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your tried seems correct just bit correction,

```
//This condition says show fb comment on all pages but navigation_bar
if(isset($_GET['catagory']) && $_GET['catagory'] != "navigatie_bar")
{
    echo " <div class='fb-comments'></div>";
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: wow that's a fast reaction ! I can't get it to work :S Do i need to put entire line in the div like                         <div class="fb-comments" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div> ?

Comment: Can you describe , what not works ? Have you debug `$_GET['catagory']` ?

Comment: Well if i type the echo like this <div class="fb-comments"></div> excactly the way it is in my template then it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'fb' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Can you [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) your code ? I guess you're using incorrect quotes.

Comment: well if put your code in my php file index.php were i display the template with content nothing happens or changes and no errors. But when i type the div exactly as in the template like <div class="fb-comments"></div> with the double "" it gives the error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'fb' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: It works ! thanks mate, posted it in my template file and now it works ! Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for-

```
 <?php

    if (isset($_GET['catagory']))
    {
       $catagory = $_GET['categorie'];

        if $catagory = navigatie_bar
        {
          //here something that says: then don't display <div class="fb-comments'></div>
        }

    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $category?>" id="tohide"/>
    <div id="comment">comments....</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready({
    var id=$("tohide").val();
    $("#"+id).hide();
    });
    </script>
```